# ¿Cómo Agregar Datos a un Objeto (arreglo)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-html-service

soy nueva en trabajar con apps scrpit y estoy trabajando con una tabla en la cual al momento de que cambia el valor de la celda J (9) a Rechazado envía un email, el código (basado en un código encontrado en red) funciona sin embargo ahora quisiera agregar que después de que se envió, agregue en la comuna M (12) un Si, pero al ser un objeto de un arreglo no me funciona el setValue (candidato.enviado.setValue("Sí")), también intente con push (como aparece en el código) pero tampoco me ha funcionado.

Este es el código con el que estoy trabajando:

```
function enviarCorreos() {
  const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  libro.setActiveSheet(libro.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1"));
  const hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const filas = hoja.getRange("A2:M").getValues();
  
  for (indiceFila in filas) {
   var candidato = crearCandidato(filas[indiceFila]);
   enviarCorreo(candidato);
  }
}

  function crearCandidato(datosFila) {
    const candidato = {
      info1: datosFila[0],
      email: datosFila[1],
      info2: datosFila[2],
      info3: datosFila[3],
      info4: datosFila[4],
      info5: datosFila[5],
      info6: datosFila[6],
      info7: datosFila[7],
      info8: datosFila[8],
      disposicion: datosFila[9],
      info9: datosFila[10],
      info10: datosFila[11],
      enviado: datosFila[12],
    };
    return candidato;
  }

  function enviarCorreo(candidato) {
    if (candidato.email == "") return;
    
    const plantilla = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Formato Correo');
    plantilla.candidato = candidato;
    const mensaje = plantilla.evaluate().getContent();
    
    if (candidato.disposicion == "RECHAZADO" && candidato.enviado == ""){
          MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: candidato.email,
          subject: "Rechazado",
          htmlBody: mensaje,
        })
        candidato.push("Si");
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
datosFila=['desconocido','.gmail','Si']
 candidato ={ 
      info:datosFila[0],
     
     email:datosFila[1],
     
    
     
     enviado: datosFila[2]
     
     };
    
    let candidatoSi={...candidato,email:'jx@gmail',enviado:'Si'};
console.log(candidatoSi)
```

> Con spread operator podes modificar propiedades de un   objeto y permanecerá inalterable el objeto original

```
let candidatoSi={...candidato,enviado:'Si'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ver el "Si" en la hoja de cálculo no es suficiente con actualizar los datos en el arreglo, debes incluir una operación de escritura por ejemplo usando `SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue`, de hecho, no es necesario actualizar el arreglo.

Una manera de hacer esto es pasar la hoja y la fila ( el índice de la fila  + 1) a `enviarCorreo`. En otras palabras, reemplaza

```
enviarCorreo(candidato)
```

por

```
enviarCorreo(candidato,hoja,indiceFila + 1)
```

y reemplaza

```
function enviarCorreo(candidato) {
```

y

```
 candidato.push("Si");
```

por

```
function enviarCorreo(candidato, hoja, fila) {
```

y

```
hoja.getRange(fila, 13).setValue("Si")
```

respectivamente.

---

Pasar la fila como  `indiceFila + 1` es debido a que los arreglos usan índices base cero pero `getRange` usa índices base 1.

NOTAS: El código es ineficiente al basar la obtención de la hoja con base en la hoja activa ya que están usando más llamadas de las necesarias para obtener el mismo resultado además de evitar "efectos colaterales", en este caso, activar una hoja. Para solucionar esto reemplaza

```
 const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  libro.setActiveSheet(libro.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1"));
  const hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

por

```
 const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const hoja = libro.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");
```